# How I can set auth type to pre emptive with guzzlehttp client

Tags: php, authentication, guzzle, preemptive

```
$response=$client->request("POST",$url,[

    "body"=>$soap,
    "auth"=>["blabla","blabla"]
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8',
    ],

]);
```

my php code but I want set auth type, how I can set auth type?

Answer (score 0):

The [authentication type](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/v3.8.1/src/Client.php#L356) can be passed as the third item in the "auth" array and can be any of ["basic", "digest", "ntlm"](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/v3.8.1/docs/http-client/client.rst#auth)

```
"auth" => ["<user>", "<pwd>", "<auth_type>"]
```